# Pinned files are not unpinned on the taskbar in pinned applications

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel-2016

The problem is this. Excel is pinned to the taskbar.
When you right-click, a list of pinned files and recent files appears. Some files in the Pinned ones cannot be unpinned from the list. The files were moved or deleted, in fact only a part was moved when the location of the Documents library was changed. Some are on the same path as they were.

I tried to detach via the = detach icon and remove from the list. Nothing happens files are also present in the list

[image: Screenshot of application's taskbar menu]

Answer (score 0):

Click on Start and then **Settings** first. Then click on **Personalization**- select **Start**- turn **off** **Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start or the taskbar**:

[image]

Comment: The question is not in the last used files, but in the pinned ones. There are no problems with the latter. Disabling their display does not solve the problem of pinned files